# Flex Security Sandbox Violation just started happening

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

I have an http handler built and running on my website server.  Code in flex generates a http request then navigates to the handler, which generates and streams back file information for the user to download.

Basically the request sends image data and the return result is a pptx stream with the image data in a powerpoint slide.

This worked fantastically this morning until about an hour ago.  I have no idea what changed, but every swf I am building which attempts to access this handler is now giving me:

*** Security Sandbox Violation ***
Connection to https://g1.localhost/Turm/BounceBack.aspx halted - not permitted from https://g1.localhost/Turm/FlashApps/ImageAndExporting.swf?debug=true

I even fully qualified the BounceBack.aspx name (it was a relative url until just now) in case something was confusing the flash player, but as you can see, the url request and the swf are loaded from exactly the same domain (even the same virtual app in the web domain).

I have even added the physical filepath as a 'trusted folder' in my flash player security settings.

What gives? Anyone have any suggestions?

Using the Apache 4.9.1 SDK and latest version of flashplayer.
As mentioned, this worked all day yesterday and this morning.  I cannot figure out what has changed, but am having no luck resolving the issue, source code has not changed.

Comment: I have to ask the silly/obvious question: is the thing that changed the fact that you're now running it on a server, whereas before you were running it locally?

Comment: No, its all a website, it just happens to be wholly contained on my local machine, but its an IIS hosted website (g1.localhost).  The swf is loaded via an aspx page belonging to the website, the handlers are registered in the website, etc.

Comment: And as an update, just deployed my solution into our build and test environments.  Both give the same sandbox violation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally figured out what changed.  I move the navigation to my ASPX handler into a seperate method that delays invoation till after a UI update.  Becuase I use the same ui components for printing as well as exporting, I tested the updates with the print feature and that worked without error.  About an our later, I noticed the handlers were failing.  Since the url request is not handled inside a UI interaction event (Like MouseEvent.CLICK) the flash player was preventing the call.  Once I moved the navigation back into the event handler, the sandbox violation went away.

If you ask me, not a very good error message due to the actual problem encountered, but ... you learn something every day.